# Probability that every box contains at least one ball, when m balls are thrown into n boxes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image: Part A]

Part A asks the probability of every box containing at least one ball, in the case when 6 balls are thrown into 5 boxes. As each box should contain at least one ball, the number of possible cases is identical as the number of onto functions from set m which contains 6 elements to set n which contains 5 elements. The below shows my solving for Part A:

[image: Part A solving]

However, here's the issue.

[image: Part B]

Part B asks the probability of every box containing at least one ball, in the case when 150 balls are thrown into 100 boxes. Using the identical approach for solving Part A, I considered the number of possible cases as the number of onto functions from set m which contains 150 elements to set n which contains 100 elements.

The below is my solving:

[image: Part B solving]

Referring to the solution sheet, I apparently got Part A correct, but the answer for Part B was different. The solution used a different approach for Part B, by subtracting the probability of at least 1 box being empty from 1. While my answer for Part B got an approximate answer of $1.51*10^{-6}$, the solution resulted in an approximate probability of $7.46*10^{-7}$.

[image: Difference in solution for Part B]

I'm not sure why I got Part A right, but not Part B, despite using an identical approach for a similar case which only used different numbers.

Also, what is the ***simplest*** approach for finding the probability in this situation?

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Both approaches should give the same answer when they are done correctly. However, a computation using *Mathematica 12* suggests both the suggested numerical values to part B are incorrect. Using the exact value of the sum (which is too long to write here), we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}(100-k)^{150}\approx 5.742 \times 10^{284}, $$ and so, the desired probability is about $$5.742 \times10^{-16}. $$ So I suspect that the discrepancy is due to numerical errors rather than the methods themselves.